# Fatal Error Magento Backend for UnSecure Address Change

Tags: magento, ssl, magento-1.8, insecure-connection

I have SSL. i searching mysql request CPU usage in SSL SSH or Apache Subjects.

im try on this, my unsecure address is,

UnSecure Address: https://www.example.com

to change

UnSecure Address: http://www.example.com

and my admin panel is down. Error is;

```
Fatal Error "Class 'Mgt_Base_Helper_Data' not found in /home/server/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

And now my backend

```
There has been an error processing your request


Mage registry key "_singleton/mgt_base/feed" already exists

Trace:
#0 /home/server/public_html/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/server/public_html/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::register('_singleton/mgt_...', false)
#2 /home/server/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21330): Mage::getSingleton('mgt_base/feed')
#3 /home/server/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('adminhtml_contr...', Array)
#4 /home/server/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(159): Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_contr...', Array)
#5 /home/server/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13861): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /home/server/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18234): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#7 /home/server/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17768): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home/server/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20368): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home/server/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/server/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

How can i fix this previous setings or How can i set unsecure adress without backend?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have install magento in PHP 5.4. Apply magento patch for PHP 5.4 or downgradr PHP to 5.3, and then clear cache (flush storage)